# C++ header and cpp file constructor multiple error

Tags: c++, constructor, header-files, clion

I am coding in C++ using Clion.

I am trying to make a `Date.cpp` file and a `Date.h` file.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include "Date.h"

// Date constructor
Date::Date(int year, int month, int day)
{
    SetDate(year, month, day);
}

// Date member function
void Date::SetDate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    m_month = month;
    m_day = day;
    m_year = year;
}
```

```cpp
class Date
{
private:
    int m_year;
    int m_month;
    int m_day;

public:
    Date(int year, int month, int day);

    void SetDate(int year, int month, int day);

    int getYear() { return m_year; }
    int getMonth() { return m_month; }
    int getDay() { return m_day; }
};

// Date constructor
Date::Date(int year, int month, int day)
{
    SetDate(year, month, day);
}

// Date member function
void Date::SetDate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    m_month = month;
    m_day = day;
    m_year = year;
}
```

I keep getting these errors:

> multiple definition of Date::Date(int, int, int)

and

> multiple definition of Date::SetDate(int, int, int)

How should I reorganize my code so it stops saying I have multiple definitions?

Comment: This is from personal experience, there might be a better way of doing it. Having the Date class in the header means you can use it in multiple cpp files by referencing it with #include. I usually reserve headers for common classes/structs and cpp files for algorithms and internal classes/structs.

Comment: please provide a [mre] as text not images

Answer (score 0):

According to your pictures you do have multiple definitions. I.e. if you have a function defined (written) in a .cpp file you cannot write it as well in a header.

If you try to put implementation in a header without .cpp file. leaveve it only in .h file and prepend definition with inline keyword i.e.:

```
inline Date::Date(int year, int month, int day) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the time! I understand now :) !

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are seeing are because your `.h` and `.cpp` files are both defining the same `Date::Date()` and `Date::SetDate()` implementation bodies.  Remove them from the `.h` file as they don't belong there, since they are in the `.cpp` file.

In general, an `.h` file should be for *declarations* and *inline definitions* (ie, like your `get..()` methods), while a `.cpp` file should be for *non-line definitions*.

Date.h

```
#ifndef DateH // don't forget a header guard!
#define DateH

class Date
{
private:
    int m_year;
    int m_month;
    int m_day;

public:
    Date(int year, int month, int day);

    void SetDate(int year, int month, int day);

    // these are OK here!
    int getYear() { return m_year; }
    int getMonth() { return m_month; }
    int getDay() { return m_day; }

    // Or, you can move their definitions into the .cpp file, if you want...
    /*
    int getYear();
    int getMonth();
    int getDay();
    */
};

#endif
```

Date.cpp

```cpp
#include "Date.h"

// Date constructor
Date::Date(int year, int month, int day)
{
    SetDate(year, month, day);
}

// Date member function
void Date::SetDate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    m_month = month;
    m_day = day;
    m_year = year;
}

// If you choose to move their definitions here...
/*
int Date::getYear()
{
    return m_year;
}

int Date::getMonth()
{
    return m_month;
}

int Date::getDay()
{
    return m_day;
}
*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the time! I understand now !